# Is it okay to have exposed 12/2 romex?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am outfitting a shed with an electrical system. The inside walls are currently unsheathed, and I do not plan to sheath them. I was not sure if I can install Romex directly stapled to the studs without wall sheathing. Is this okay or do I have to use conduit or armored cable?

Comment: Are you talking about stapled to the edges of the studs, or run through bored holes in the studs?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am talking about bored holes similar to normal residential wiring, just without wall sheathing.

Answer (score 2):

Above 8’ it would be ok but below that 1/2” Sheetrock or wood panels, plywood , osb ect.

Comment: yep, needs to be covered (or use BX). In my shed, I found that OSB was actually less expensive than sheetrock, and I didn't care about the looks, so a simple cheap paint from the "mistake" bin was fine.

Comment: OSB, plywood etc. also have the advantages of being much better to screw into. If you want to hang minor shelves or racks, this can help.